# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/core/migrations/0005_recipe_image.py'

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, database-migration

when i am trying makemigrations on dockerised django application, got this permissionError
Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN  pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache jpeg-dev && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual musl-dev zlib zlib-dev && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt &&\
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol

USER django-user
COPY . .
```

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - dev_static_data:/vol/web
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_container
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
   depends_on:
     - db
   environment:
     - DB_HOST=db
     - DB_NAME=postgres
     - DB_USER=postgres
     - DB_PASS=postgres
 db:
   image: postgres
   volumes:
     - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
   environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
   container_name: postgres_db
volumes:
  postgres_db:
  dev_static_data:
```

When i run: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations",
the error message is:

```
[+] Creating 1/0
✔ Container postgres_db  Running                                                                                               
0.0s
Migrations for 'core':
core/migrations/0005_recipe_image.py
   - Add field image to recipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
     main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 
  442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 
   436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 
       412, 
      in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 
       458, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 
       106, in wrapper
   res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site- 
  packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 259, in handle
        self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site- 
    packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 363, in 
    write_migration_files
      with open(writer.path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
      '/app/core/migrations/0005_recipe_image.py'
```

I applied the solution suggested in this Stack Overflow thread, but it didn't work